# adding objects to a class list, from another class in Python

Tags: python, class

How could I modify the classes below so that when a new instance of Pet
is created, it is automatically added to its Owner's list of pets?

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []
```

Comment: in `Pet.__init__()`: `self.owner.pets.append(self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
owner1 = Owner(name="Juan")

pet = Pet(name="foo", owner=owner1)

owner1.pets += pet
```

or change your pet **init**

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        owner.pets.append(self)
```

Comment: Realy no, fixed!

Comment: You can't concatenate a non-iterable to a list. Change it to `owner.pets += [self]`

Comment: Or how about `owner.pets.append(self)`?

Comment: yeah, sorry, that "owner.pets.append(self)" is the correct syntax, seeing that self will be an object, and objects is not iterable

Comment: Excellent, many thanks. The change on pet init worked perfectly!